# jboss deployment error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jboss

I'm having a problem while deploying a spring project on jboss. 
Well, here's the problem, I have in the file applicationContext.xml this bean definition

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
<property name="dataSource"> 
    <ref local="dataSource"/>
</property> 
<property name="mappingDirectoryLocations"> 
    <list> 
    <value> 
        classpath:tn/com/zuro/ris/domain/hibernate/hbm/
    </value> 
    </list> 
</property> 

 ...
```

and i have the file Patient.hbm.xml in the directory classpath:tn/com/zuro/ris/domain/hibernate/hbm
When I deploy the war in jboss, I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [tn/com/zuro/ris/domain/hibernate/hbm/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfsfile:/C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/tn/com/zuro/ris/domain/hibernate/hbm/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check if your really have the desired path and have hbm mappings there
- try removing the trailing slash (the example doesn't have one, it should be a problem but try)
- check permissions on the directory

Comment: I have the hbm mappings in C:/jboss/server/default/deploy/war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/tn/com/zuro/ris/domain/hibernate/hbm, and i tried removing the trailing slash, the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 2.5.x, you are probably running into this issue:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5120

Basically, Spring requires protocol specific support for class path scanning and did not cope with JBoss' vfsfile-protocol for access to its virtual file system.

Comment: and how can I fix it? I should use spring 3.0.x?